# Save live data from data logger to csv file by python

Tags: python

I have a data logger to record the temperature. I want to save these data and epoch time in a csv file. I tried the following code, there is no error reporting but the csv file is empty. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

```
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mcp9600
import time

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL,board.SDA,frequency = 100000)
mcp = adafruit_mcp9600.MCP9600(i2c, 0x60, tctype = "J")


with open ("/home/pi/Documents/test.csv", "a") as log:
    while True:
        temp = mcp.temperature
        temptime = time.time()
        log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(str(temptime),str(temp)))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Your file is _buffered_, which means the OS doesn't write data right away. It only does so periodically, in larger chunks of data, since disk IO is relatively slow. You can put `log.flush()` immediately after the write, and each line should appear as its written.

Comment: It solves my problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming those libraries you're importing are working correctly, I think this is because the writer is not flushing the buffer, so it appears like nothing is being written.

The solution would be to flush with `log.flush()` after each time you write a log.

Try a simpler example:

A)

```
import time


def go():
    i = 0
    with open("/home/some/dir/test.csv", "a") as nice:
        while True:
            nice.write(f"hello,{i},{time.time()}\n")
            i += 1
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    go()
```

versus

B)

```
import time


def go():
    i = 0
    while True:
        with open("/home/some/dir/test.csv", "a") as nice:
            nice.write(f"hello,{i},{time.time()}\n")
            i += 1
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    go()
```

When I refresh the file in case A, new rows do not appear to be written. They are in case B, though.

If I modify case A) and add `nice.flush()` after each write, it fixes the issue.

The above two blocks are just to demonstrate what you're seeing. I'm not suggesting you do one or the other. Ultimately, I would not suggest doing anything like this, and I would instead use the `logging` package and configure a proper logger if you're indeed trying to create log files.

Comment: It's not really that the file is open or closed, but rather that it is _buffered_. The OS will write data to the file whenever it's "a good time". You would see each line here if you put `nice.flush()` immediately after the write.

Comment: Thanks I will modify accordingly